# Time series-regression analysis- Understanding violaton of indepence assumption

Tags: correlation, time-series, regression-analysis

I am studying Time series using regression analysis.

I know that when using time series data the assumption that the erros are independent cannot be satisfied.

However, analysing the residual plot:

[image]
In My opinion, it  does not have a positive autocorrelation because I cannot see a cyclic pattern. Also, it does not show a negative autocorrelation.

I think that there is a random pattern and it indicates that there is no autocorrelation or little autocorrelation.

I did a Durbin-Watson test to confirm the above ideas and the value for the test is 2.349. It is greater than 2 but very close to 2, so I assumed that there is no autocorrelation.

Additionally I checked that the p-values for the coefficients are very small, less than 5%. It means that they are all significant.
[image]

Also, the value for the f-test and p-value show that the model is significant

All these, show that autocorrelation is not a problem in this case and that the assumption that the errors are independent are not being violated. However I am confused because I am using time series data where I used Dummy variables for seasonality and according to what I read this assumption is not satisfied when using Time series but in my case I think that there is no autocorrelation.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey you may want to try CrossValidation S.E. for a potentially more suitable help :). That is an S.E. for statistics as far as I am aware.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I don't understand what you meant by that. Can you provide more information? Thank you

Comment: No worries. The site is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions. Good luck